# How to shuffle rows of 3 dimensional numpy array?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I have 3 dimensional array having 3 rows(sample), 2 columns and 4 features. I want to shuffle three sample. But the following command gives error that only size 1 arrays can be converted to python lists. How can I do that?

```
`x= np.arange(3*2*4).reshape(3,2,4)
perm = np.arange(x[0])`
```

Comment: You aren't trying to shuffle anything here. Have you checked to see the output of x[0]?

You will find that you are getting an array and are using that as input to arange which requires an integer.

Comment: As a continue to @David you might want to produce permutation, so you need use `x.shape[0]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take the following example:

```
x = np.arange(2 * 3).reshape([3, 2])
perm = np.arange(x.shape[0])
```

As well you can print `x.shape` and see the result tuple `(3, 2)`, so its zero's element is `3`.

Comment: x is giving me 3 dimensional array i.e., (3,2,4). I want to pick up 3 and then use that in np.arange(3) so that it should give me [0,1,2]. This is what I want to do

Comment: For what purpose do you need the `[0, 1, 2]` array? Because this is not what you asked.
Also, please explain what 3 you want, the first element of `(3, 2, 4)` or its length.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer has mentioned, you need to use shuffle, and it doesn't touch anything other than the first axis (your samples) according to [the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html).

> This function only shuffles the array along the first axis of a multi-dimensional array.